# Set BottomNavigationView title next to icon

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, material-components-android

Is it possible to set title next to the icon in BottomNavigationView without using any other View than BottomNavigationView? I know how to do it with LinearLayout combined with TextViews and ImageViews but it would be better to use some existing XML attribute or something.

I found that [material.io](https://material.io/components/bottom-navigation/#placement) have it as an example here:

[image]